# How can I pick the last datum from SQL and sum 1 then save it again in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I have a situation where I need to select the last datum from SQL, and save it in WPF using C#, then I need to sum 1 to this datum, then save that in the database (is like a order number from a delivery thing I don't know). Sorry for my English.

Comment: Use `Top 1` and `order by <column> desc` in your SQL query.

Comment: but i need to work in the visual studio wpf c#. no in the sql:(

Comment: I don't know how are you getting data from database in the c# code. But if you are executing SQL query to get data from SQL then you still need to execute proper query to get proper data.

Comment: are you using entity framework?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.